# Python, sorting a .txt file scores from highest to lowest

Tags: python, sorting

I have successfully coded my program so that it sorts the 'scores' in a text file in alphabetical order.

```
#Sort Alphabetically
with open(current_class, 'r') as f:
    StudentList = f.readlines()
    for line in sorted(StudentList):
        print(line.rstrip())
```

Can you provide me with the key I would use to sort the scores from Highest to Lowest? I also believe that 'reverse=True' when sorting highest to lowest.

I will also provide the code I use to save the last three scores of each student taking my quiz to see if that proves as any help.

```
current_class = Classes[student_class]
class_format = "{} scored {}".format(name, Score)

users = defaultdict(lambda:deque([], maxlen=3))
with open(current_class) as f:
    for line in f:
        student, grade = line.split(' scored ')
        users[student].append(int(grade))

users[name].append(Score)

with open(current_class, 'w') as f: 
    for user, scores in users.items():
        for score in scores:
            class_format_updated = "{} scored {}\n".format(user, Score)
            f.write(class_format_updated)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a step where you parse the input as floats.

```
with open(current_class, 'r') as f:
    studentList = [float(line) for line in f.readlines()]
    for score in reversed(sorted(studentList)):
        print(score)
```

Update:

If I understand your follow up comment and the structure of the input text correctly, then this should work:

```
with open(current_class, 'r') as f:
    studentList = f.readlines()

    # this will sort the list based on the float that comes after " scored "
    studentList.sort(key = lambda line: float(line.split(" scored ")[-1]))

    for score in reversed(studentList):
        print(score)
```

Comment: As you can see, my program outputs ('{} scored {}\n).format(name, Score). So it isn't as simple as that, do I need to .split the 'scored'? If so what would happen to the '\n' after the second '{}'.

Comment: I see. I updated the response based on my understanding of the input text structure.

Comment: Thank you!! Last thing!! If I wanted to sort all the scores of user into an average, what would I change in the key?

Comment: If the input file contains multiple records per user, you'd have to read them in to, say, a dictionary of lists first, then iterate through that dictionary computing an average for each individual.

Comment: Thanks, can I also ask you what the [-1] is responsible for doing? I just want to make sure I comprehend the code so I avoid this issue in the future

Comment: `line.split(" scored ")` breaks the input line using " scored " as the delimiter. The result is a list which in a typical case will consist of something like `["Christian", "92.3"]`. The `[-1]` grabs the last element from that list, `"92.3"`. I almost used `[1]` which grabs the second element from the list. However, this would fail in some exceptional degenerate cases, like if the name of the student contained " scored ".